# Are there sites in the network that we could submit community ads to?

Tags: discussion

I think it would be nice to have community ads to advertise our site on other sites in the network. But usually sites submit community ads to sites that tend to share the same interests.

On one hand, pets has a broad reach since practically everyone has a pet, or has interacted with a pet. But on the other hand, it doesn't really make sense to me to advertise on some of the sites that are geared towards programming (unless we have a really clever ad).

Are there any sites in the network where it would make sense to submit community advertisements to?

Comment: The trick is finding one not in beta... Most of the ones that I could see basic synergy with are also beta sites.

Comment: @JohnCavan why limit to sites not in beta?

Comment: &JamesJenkins - I think they have to be, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I found Monica's answer and it seems to correctly support your position http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/could-we-have-community-ads-too/1997#1997

Comment: Yeah, only graduated sites can run ads, so those are the ones we can target.  Another beta site I'm active on is currently discussing this, so two points that are fresh in my mind: we can advertise *the site*, and/or we can advertise *specific questions*.  So if you can find a good, well-written, well-answered question here that would be of specific interest on some other community, please propose that in answers!

Comment: Also specific tags, I guess.  I don't know if any of ours are good for this.

Comment: @MonicaCellio [Technically beta sites *could* get community ads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248216/251229) but I doubt any will have them...

Comment: @MonicaCellio Good point about advertising specific questions. I did that with the Etiquette proposal on Area51 (which never got beyond commitment phase in the end) - took a few travel-related etiquette questions and put them in a community ad for Travel SE and took a few work-related etiquette questions and put them in a community ad for The Workplace. I think if I'd just put an ad in for "etiquette" it would have been downvoted, but my approach seemed to work.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it, perhaps Travel is a place we could advertise some specific questions. Sadly, Parenting and Biology are both still in beta (I can think of some targeted questions for them).

Comment: Parenting and biology are both in beta, but now that you mention travel.se I remember we had some quesitons about bringing birds on airplanes that might be a good use for ads there.

Answer (score 3):

Taking Monica's idea of advertising specific questions:

Travel SE:

- [What information should we leave for a cat sitter/cattery?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7478/what-information-should-we-leave-for-a-cat-sitter-cattery)
- [Are there airlines offering possibility of flight on board with bigger dog like labrador? (intercontinental filights EUROPE-USA)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/are-there-airlines-offering-possibility-of-flight-on-board-with-bigger-dog-like)
- [How can I safely transport a chinchilla on a 15 hour car ride?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6721/how-can-i-safely-transport-a-chinchilla-on-a-15-hour-car-ride)
- [How can I transport my rabbit using a bicycle?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/how-can-i-transport-my-rabbit-using-a-bicycle)
- [How can I help my cat not get carsick?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/how-can-i-help-my-cat-not-get-carsick)

And [loads](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) more!

The Workplace

- [My pit bull cries for 5 minutes when I leave for work. Is he ok?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/my-pit-bull-cries-for-5-minutes-when-i-leave-for-work-is-he-ok)
- [My dog is destroying things and peeing inside when I am at work. How can I get him to stop?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/my-dog-is-destroying-things-and-peeing-inside-when-i-am-at-work-how-can-i-get-h)
- [How should I accomodate my cat if I travel for work?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/how-should-i-accomodate-my-cat-if-i-travel-for-work)
- [How can I ensure my cat won't resent me after being alone for an 8-hour work day?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6081/how-can-i-ensure-my-cat-wont-resent-me-after-being-alone-for-an-8-hour-work-day)

Sites people might be able to think of clever ads for:

- [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) - there are plenty of games with animals in
- [Movies and TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com) - likewise